# Why doesn't inotifywait report modifications made to battery capacity file?

Tags: inotify, battery

I want to know when my battery charge changes, and I don't want to simply run a daemon that checks on it every five seconds.

I've tried running `inotifywait -m /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity`, but it doesn't register any modifications even though `cat`-ing it every once in a while gives different results! In fact, it only reports something when I used `cat` on it, or run `acpi`. I've also tried running `inotifywait` on other files in the BAT1 directory, and found out that none have been seen made modifications to - despite giving new results with `cat`.

So why doesn't `inotifywait` report modifications? And how can I get instant updates on changes in battery level if I can't use inotify?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be a special file (as they are in /sys and /proc). So it may be that the kernel basically returns the actual value as the file is read, rather than changing the file everytime. Something like a [fuse fs with custom return functions](https://github.com/fuse-friends/fuse-native).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @rudib said in the comments, everything in `/sys` is virtual: the content of each file is created fresh from the corresponding kernel data structure whenever it's actually being read. So, there are no modifications in the sense of something writing into the file to change it.

The same goes for `/proc`.

Battery status notifications are available as *generic Netlink messages*, with family name = `acpi_event` and multicast group name `acpi_mc_group`. Unfortunately I don't know of a tool that would give easy access to Netlink messages for shell scripts, but apparently the [`pyroute2`](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2) tool can also decode netlink messages that contain ACPI events, so it might be useful as a Python code example.